# I need to download jasper reports professional trail version

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to download jasper reports professional trail version, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean the trial version?  What is your problem? Do you know the web site?  Does the web site not show you what you are looking for?  What exactly is your problem?  (As it stands, your questions sounds a bit pathetic.)

Comment: i want to buy jasper reports professional version, but before i do that i want to test it, so i need to download trial version for testing. ru clear? can u help me?

Comment: thank you.... but i have already visited the site, i know how to register, i know how to download, i just asked if u know abt it, just say yes or no, i dont need unnessary ans, thank u

Comment: @stanley: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but your question does not ask if we know about Jasper Reports.  It asks if anyone can help you download Jasper Reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JasperReports professional edition does not have a free evaluation download.  You can purchase a single user license for $249 or use the community edition version which you can download from http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport.  The pro version has extra features like flash based reports and maps along with the ability to design reports that can be used with advanced functions in JasperServer(like domains).

Comment: ... and actually the free edition is a kind of "trial" version with almost all the functionality - I've found it very well written and powerful in general.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to go to [Jaspersoft downloads](http://jaspersoft.com/downloads).  We can't register for you; we can't download it for you; we can't agree to the licence for you.  There are some things you have to do for yourself.

Comment: thank you.... but i have already visited the site, i know how to register, i know how to download, i just asked if u know abt it, just say yes or no, i dont need unnessary ans, thank u

Comment: I'm afraid you did ask how to download it, rather than if people know about it.